# Wrapping rows in Telerik MVC grid

Tags: css, telerik, telerik-grid, telerik-mvc

I have an application with a number of grids based on Telerik MVC controls.  It works wonderfully, however at low resolutions or low browser widths, I cannot get the grids to be responsive as I need them to be.

I would like to start wrapping the rows onto multiple lines when the user decides to resize down the browser (or has low res).  I prefer to NOT have the horizontal scrollbars show up as my users frequently do not see them or use them.

Can anyone provide any suggestions if this is possible to do with Telerik MVC grids?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Telerik grids are responsive by default and you just need to include proper css file present in kendo UI . As for the display of columns, you can not hide them as telerik does not allow you to hide any column and minimum width of column is same as column name width .